# How to hide records for a specific time period for individual users?

Tags: php, mysql, session

How do I hide a retrieved row from a database, on click, for a specified time, but interesting only one user?

Example: user Nobody opens the site, click on the result XXXX that will open a link in a new page, now on the site XXXX result has been hidden for 10 minutes preventing it to be clicked again.  Meanwhile user World joins the site, and he is able to see all the records (the modify for the user Nobody, does not affect user World too).

I was thinking about using $_SESSION to store the informations, but then it wouldn't go in conflict for all the results?

For displaying the results I use a while that will put in a table the records:

```
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM table_records";

$result = mysql_query($SQL);

while ( $rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) ) {

echo "<td><center>".$rows['id']."</center></td>";
echo "<td><center>".$rows['name']."</center></td>";
echo "<td><center>".$rows['link']."</center></td>";
echo "<td><center>".$rows['delay']."</center></td>";`
```

Delay is the actual time the link must be "hidden" from the user who clicked on it.

In poor words, I made for my users a page which shows a group of links for utilities/affiliations, but since there is 100+ links, they get confused on which they already visited.

Comment: on click create a row in another table for Nobody with a timestamp for that XXXX as you call it. That table right side of left join or what-not. In just about any routine going against that table you can clobber rows that are over 10min regardless of user going at it

Comment: Hopefully there is a valid reason for even doing this, as at 50k feet it sounds kludgie

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using a CSS a:visited style like every other web page on the planet?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily track which page are and which page aren't visited using sessions.

#### Index

```
<?php
session_start();

$sql = "SELECT * FROM table_records";

$result = mysql_query($sql);

$records = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $records[] = $row;
}
foreach ($records as $record) {
    $now = new DateTime();
    if (!array_key_exists($record, $_SESSION['records']) || ($now->getTimestamp()-$_SESSION['records'][$record]) <= 600) {
        echo "<td><center>".$record['id']."</center></td>";
        echo "<td><center>".$record['name']."</center></td>";
        echo "<td><center>".$record['link']."</center></td>";
        echo "<td><center>".$record['delay']."</center></td>";`
    } else {
        // link disabled
    }
}
?>
```

#### The page you are linking to

```
<?php
session_start();
$now = new DateTime();

$id = $_GET['id'];

if (!array_key_exists($id, $_SESSION['records'])) {
    $_SESSION['records'][$id] = $now->getTimestamp();
} elseif (array_key_exists($id, $_SESSION['records']) && ($now->getTimestamp()-$_SESSION['records'][$id]) >= 600) {
    die("Your 10 minutes have expired");
}


?>
<!-- Page here -->
```

Do keep in mind that the user can tamper with this by deleting their cookies. You could solve this by also saving the timestamps in the database and/or securing your site with a login.
shareeditdeleteflag

***Note*** `mysql_*` functions are deprecated and shouldn't be used anymore. Take a look at `mysqli_*` or `PDO`.

Comment: I tried implementing this code, but, it does not work..  it puts correctly out the data and print them into the table, but, the page am linking to, does not actually work, just a white page and it does not add the SESSION to mark the record as viewed.

Comment: Thats probably because you didn't set `$id` You need to use `$record['link'].'?id='.$record['id']`

Comment: I tought i tried that, now i'm trying to figure out whats wrong with it. I'll update you in about 5 mins.. i'll try again re-writing the ID _GET

Comment: nope, nothing, it's not working. I even tried tweaking the whole code. still blank page

Answer (score 0):

So, I actually solved the white page error by tweaking the code, however,

It does not work.
It always redirect the user to the page, even if he already viewed it..

thats the current code:

```
$waiting_time = $delay * 60;

if (!array_key_exists($id, $_SESSION['records'])) {

$_SESSION['records'][$id] = $now->getTimestamp();
header("Location: $thislink");
exit();

} elseif (array_key_exists($id, $_SESSION['records']) && ($now->getTimestamp()-$_SESSION['records'][$id]) >= $waiting_time) {

echo "Looks like you already visited this page";

} elseif (array_key_exists($id, $_SESSION['records']) && ($now->getTimestamp()-$_SESSION['records'][$id]) < $waiting_time) {

$_SESSION['records'][$id] = $now->getTimestamp();
header("Location: $thislink");
exit();

}
```